# Push affiliate publisher data into google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, affiliate

I run a blog and publish AWIN affiliate campaigns on my website.
The Awin affiliate network offers a transaction feed that automatically push near transaction notifications to a URL I am able to define.

Detailed infos: https://wiki.awin.com/index.php/Transaction_Notification

I wonder if there is a way for me to push/import this data from Awin directly into my Google Analytics account and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this feature is called [Data Import](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3191589?hl=en). What you will need is to choose a [dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) (called the import key) with which you can blend `GA` and `AWIN` data. Practically, what you might need to do is:

1. **Implement a [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) as your import key** so you can store an affiliate identifier from `AWIN` against your users in GA, this will be your blending dimension.
2. **Create other custom dimensions/metrics** as needed to hold the other data points from `AWIN`
3. [Create and import data sets](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014980?hl=en&ref_topic=6064627) on a regular basis to import new `AWIN` data

Please note that a few weeks ago [Google Data Studio](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061421?hl=en) now has a feature to blend data sets, so once step 1 is done, you could perform steps 2 and 3 in data studio (which might be easier for you as you don't need to create the extra dimensions/metrics AND  you could have your `AWIN` data in a Google Sheet synced automatically with your GDS report, thus saving you the data imports).

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly the info I am looking for :-)

Comment: You're welcome Michael, if you're happy with the answer, you can upvote it (little ^ icon above the checkmark)

Comment: I am happy with the answer and already marked your answer as usefull. Unfortunately my reputation level is to low to show my vote publicly :-/